# How to scale ecs cluster with autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I think you have 2 scaling

```
1 for ec2 instance
1 for ecs task
```

So I think flow goes like

- You get more requests
- Your tasks need more resources (cpu/memory)
- Your ecs task autoscaling kicks in and creates more task
- your ec2 autoscaling also kicks in and creates more ec2

Questions

1. your ecs needs to know newly launched ec2 (from ec2 autoscaling group) is the host that it can run on (how?)
2. I want the number of ec2 instance starts from one. 
   I think one instance is already running in the ecs cluster 
   Do I make ec2 autoscaling group start from 0?
3. ec2 autoscaling group has pricing option to use spot instance, but I didn't see such option when I created ecs cluster instances. To be clear, can I make ecs cluster with 0 ecs-instance, and let ec2 autoscaling group starts with 1 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your ecs task autoscaling kicks in and creates more task
>   your ec2 autoscaling also kicks in and creates more ec2

Your ECS task scale if there is a memory so fine it will scale and launch new container, if not enough memory then it will not launch an instance, you need to configure cloud watch alarm to scale ECS cluster based on the task scaling.

[Tutorial: Scaling Container Instances with CloudWatch Alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html)

> your ecs needs to know newly launched ec2 (from ec2 autoscaling group)
>   is the host that it can run on (how?)

ECS agent registers the new instance with the same cluster, and the new task can be placed in any instance that have available resources to handle and launch the container.

> I want the number of ec2 instance starts from one. I think one
>   instance is already running in the ecs cluster Do I make ec2
>   autoscaling group start from 0?

You should start from 1 otherwise no container  will launch and will throw error no instance found in the cluster. if you do not want run container for now then you can start from 0.

> ec2 autoscaling group has pricing option to use spot instance, but I
>   didn't see such option when I created ecs cluster instances. To be
>   clear, can I make ecs cluster with 0 ecs-instance, and let ec2
>   autoscaling group starts with 1 instance?

You can read about spot ECS cluster instance [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/powering-your-amazon-ecs-clusters-with-spot-fleet/).

> Amazon ECS is a highly scalable, high performance, container
>   management service that supports Docker containers and allows you to
>   run applications on a managed cluster of Amazon EC2 instances easily.
>   ECS already handles the placement and scheduling of containers on EC2
>   instances. When combined with Spot fleet, ECS can deliver significant
>   savings over EC2 on-demand pricing.

Comment: Since ecs cluster already runs 1 ec2 instance, setting 1 for desired capacity in ASG, makes 2 instances running.. How can I start from 1? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html is not up-to-date with current page. and it's confusing :(

Comment: No, if there is one instance in min and max there should be one instance from auto-scaling. and yes it complex as there is no out of the box feature for ECS cluster scaling. that is why people moving to fargate to no worry about underlaying infratstucture

Comment: normaly with ECS people scale task, not the ec2 instance, there should be capacity to in the isntacne to launch the new container and opmize isntance resocues https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/automatic-scaling-with-amazon-ecs/

Comment: Tutorial: Scaling Container Instances with CloudWatch Alarms => talks about ec2 scaling..  https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/compute/automatic-scaling-with-amazon-ecs/ takes different approach i guess? I'll take a look at the new link! thans!